# Postgres - Where EXISTS else use other where condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a single query that simply looks for a record based on 2 values. However, if the record doesn't exist I want to search again where 1 of the values (last name) is null. I'm trying to figure out if this is possible outside of PL/SQL through some use of EXISTS or IN keywords.

```
SELECT t.id 
FROM table t 
WHERE t.first_name = :firstName AND 
EXISTS (SELECT t.id FROM table t WHERE t.first_name = :firstName AND t.last_name = :lastName)
ELSE t.last_name IS NULL;
```

EDIT:

I have 2 records:

(1, John, null) & (2, John, Frank)

If we search for John Jonas then, we expect 1 to be returned. Alternatively, if we search for John Frank we expect 2 to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [COALESCE:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)

```sql
select t.id 
from my_table t 
where t.first_name = :firstName 
and coalesce(t.last_name, :lastName) = :lastName;
```

The above query returns all the rows where `first_name` is equal to `:firstName` and `last_name` is `null` or equal to `:lastName`. The logic you want (conditional querying) is much more complex:

```sql
with condition(do_exist) as (
    select exists(
        select from my_table
        where first_name = :firstName
        and last_name = :lastName)
)

select id
from my_table 
cross join condition
where first_name = :firstName
and case when do_exist then last_name = :lastName else last_name is null end;
```

Test it in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=807419f5c0b769b4d4ff075d7d08431d)

Comment: This query is returning more than 1 record with example records like (1, John, null) & (2, John, Frank). The problem is when we search for a record with first name & last name like (John, Jonas) then, it should be returning just the id of 1. However, in your query with coalesce your not actually comparing against the t.last_name column so, it ends up returning both records because it essentially just looks for records with t.first_name = :firstName which is not what I want because I also want it to look for t.last_name IS NULL

Comment: See the updated answer for an optimized query.